# How to print multiple Zero after the decimal number when I calculate the floating numbers in C++? I am solving URI 1005 problem

Tags: c++

How to print multiple Zero after the decimal number when I calculate the floating numbers in C++?

I am Using `std::cout<<"MEDIA = "<<std::setprecision(6)<<av;` to show 5 digits after decimal number. Actually, I am trying to solve [URI 1005 (Average 1) problem.](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1005)

It's working but it's not working when the calculation result is decimal(like: 5,9,10). Then it's not showing the 5 00000 digits after the decimal number.

This is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float A=0;float B=0;
    cin>>A;
    cin>>B;

    float av=((A*3.5)+(B*7.5))/11;
    std::cout<<"MEDIA = "<<std::setprecision(6)<<av<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here not getting the 10.00000 if I enter both input 10.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include [`std::fixed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) in your output printing:

```cpp
#include <iomanip>

std::cout << "MEDIA = " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(6) << av << std::endl;
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/rKndC4)

Comment: This is not what I am wanting to do. Here I am calculating the average value. Please, see that result I want, Exp1: 4.5+4=8.50000 Exp2: 4.5+4.5=9.00000. This is I want to do.

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific. What EXACTLY is not working for you? `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(6) << 8.5f` displays `8.500000`, and `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(6) << 9.0f` displays `9.000000`, as expected.  Did you see [the example](https://ideone.com/2mlUst) I posted for you?